# Javascript - Unable to execute catch block for testing

Tags: javascript, try-catch, parseint

I need to test this code for which I am unable to enter this inner catch block. Can anybody help with which value will work for catch block.

```
if (!isNaN(num) && num !== null && num !== undefined && num != '') {
        try {
            return parseInt(num);
        } catch (e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Please don't give suggestion to change this code. I just need to test this.

Comment: If you want us to help you with your test then please provide what you are currently doing to test this code snippet. See [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could also try reading the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) docs to see if reaching the `catch` block is even possible from `parseInt`. Hint.... can it throw an error?

Comment: Due to some restrictions, i can't provide you the code. It is for unit testing. I just need a value which can get into catch block

Comment: MCRE doesn't mean proprietary code, just a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ECMAScript 5.1 specification for `parseInt()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) it doesn't throw an exception, so your `catch` can never be executed.

**Edit**: But, it calls `toString()`, and `toString()` can be forced to throw:

```js
var IExplode = {
    toString: () => {
        throw "up";
    }
}

parseInt(IExplode);
```

However, this dies on the `!isNan(IExplode)` guard, so you could implement some way of not throwing until the nth invocation, for instance.